# What is the correct way to import styles and controls from another assembly into a WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I have a Class Library project with default controls and styles in. I created a Nuget package from this project. I then tried to use the Package Manager in Visual Studio to add a reference to another project, but this is where I have the problem.

The reference gets added successfully, but then I cannot access the `App.xaml` file from the packaged project in a `ResourceDictionary` within the `MergedDictionaries` property of the consumer project's `App.xaml` file:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DefaultStyles;component/App.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I get an inline error on this line (not shown in the Error List) stating:

> Assembly 'DefaultStyles' is not referenced by this project

But it *is* referenced by the project. I can see the reference in the Project References and I have Intellisense for the controls that are in the referenced project.

Also, the project builds successfully, but I have two similar errors displayed in the Error List:

> The name "ImageWithSingleTextLine" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DefaultStyles.ItemTemplates;assembly=DefaultStyles".

But it does exist in there and I get Intellisense for it, so that if I try to write the line again, it auto completes for me... and *then* gives me the error again. No amount of cleaning, building and rebuilding will fix the issue.

It's not until I try to run the application that I get a further clue. A `XamlParseException` is thrown from the `App.xaml.cs` constructor, stating:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'DefaultStyles.App' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

It also has an inner Exception of type `InvalidOperationException`:

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

So, it seems like that is the root cause of the problem. In the default styles project, I have extensively used the `App.xaml` file, and added an event handler into the `App.xaml.cs` code behind file.

My question is how can I make this all work?

Comment: Why would you use an `App.xaml` file in the control library? This makes no sense at all I am afraid. The control library should only contain styles and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly discovered, you cannot have more than a single instance of the `Application` class in one `AppDomain`. The solution is to move the contents of your `App.xaml` file into a `ResourceDictionary` and use that instead. You can still use a code behind file for a standard `ResourceDictionary`, if you need to.